# What Bronze Age Jobs Couldn't be Replaced by Extremely Well Trained Animals?

Tags: technology, fauna, avian, manufacturing, bronze-age

In this setting magpies and mammoths have been domesticated for hundreds of millennia, allowing them to become far more diligent and trainable than dogs by a wide margin.

The mammoths come in full sized and dwarf breeds, and the magpies similarly come in breeds from wild magpie up to raven sized.

Both these species have become smarter, but not dramatically so. They do *come off* as ***much*** more intelligent however, as they have very good memory, can learn huge numbers of words, and are all incredibly attentive to body language like [Clever Hans.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clever_Hans)

The animals are also more dextrous than their wild counterparts when manipulating objects, but not up to a point that would require major physical changes.

For reference the magpies capacity for rote memorization is such that it has allowed the construction of an entire bird based internet. So many jobs that requires minimal intelligence and no manual dexterity will be replaced.

What I can't predict however is exactly which tasks are and aren't limited to humans by virtue of the required dexterity.
For instance mass manufacturing of some goods like pottery is *extremely* old, but I don't know how much finesse a pottery wheel requires.

**Given these mammoths and magpies physical and cognitive limitations, what physical labor would still be limited to people?**

Part of series with:
Just How Omnipresent Would Cheap Cross Laminated Spider Silk Be?
How much would this alien parasite increase crop yields?
How Big Can An Ancient Bird Powered Glider Get?

Comment: [Jared Diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guns,_Germs,_and_Steel) has entered the chat...

Comment: "_hundreds of millennia_" would predate things like the evolution of neanderthals by quite some margin, and be a _very_ long time before the proposed dates for the domestication of dogs. I'm not gonna tell you that it is impossible, but you're pushing human technological advances a long way back into the past which will have substantial knock-on effects on your fictional prehistory.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Yes this scenario is pretty hugely divergent from our own and has multiple hominid species. I just want to know the kinds of labor that would be replaced in early civilization.

Comment: You must be a MacCaulay fan! I love your world already!

Comment: The edits changed the original question to the opposite: The original question asked about jobs suitable for the specified animals but the latest version (as of now) asks about jobs that are not suitable for these animals. Edits like these are not in line with the WB.SE rules.

Comment: intelligent creatures make poor slaves/llivestock, sooner or later they decide to do what they want to do and not what the screaming monkey wants them to do.

Comment: @John That's why I specified that they *aren't* dramatically smarter.

Comment: @VakusDrake I'm talking about those animals as they are right now. elephants and primates are extremally  difficult to domesticate, and basically useless for labor

Comment: @John Elephants weren't really properly domesticated because of the insane cost that would entail for a sedentary civilization, but they were useful despite that. Wild wolves aren't exactly the easiest to train either, but to use that as evidence would miss the point of domestication.

Comment: @VakusDrake wolves are way dumber than elephants, and way easier to train, also since you mention wolves, one thing we do when we domesticate animals is unknowingly breed them to be dumber because it makes them easier to control. wolves are more intelligent than dogs, the same has happened to basically everything we have domesticated.

Comment: @John The fundamental issue here is that there's no direct evidence for intelligence *itself* making animals less cooperative. You're also conflating correlation with causation with regards to our domestic animals being dumber: They get dumber because they aren't being selected for it and possibly because of us selecting for neoteny.

Comment: @VakusDrake they get dumber because dumber animals are easier to control, animals do what they want to do not what you want them to do, thats a general rule in animal behavior anyway but it is easier to control an animals behavior when its behavior is simple and easy to predict.  a very intelligent animal like an elephant has much the same problem controlling humans have, it doesn't want to do hard labor anymore than you do, and its smart enough to know it does not have to.

Comment: @John As I pointed out before the evidence you've put forth doesn't prove what you're claiming. We already know of reasons domestic animals would tend to become less intelligent regardless of whether that would impact trainability.

Comment: Such as? you are not just removing constraints, since brain loss occurs across the board,  https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-70877-0_13 domestication actually creates very powerful selective pressures. again ask yourself, why don't you want to do hard labor because the same answer will be true for an intelligent animal. animls with larger brains show a GREATER loss of brain mass during domestication. https://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/82979 obviously there is a stronger selective pressure against intelligence during domestication.

Comment: @John As I previously pointed out we aren't selecting for intelligence, so the default position should be that costly (which brains definitely are) superfluous features will quickly become diminished *in proportion to how expensive they are*. Just like species colonizing caves will shrink their eyes and lose pigmentation in the pitch black. Consequently you should expect this evidence under my view anyway. Similarly we often indirectly select for neoteny (see Russian fox experiment) which has lots of spandrels besides the behavioral changes we want.

Comment: Neoteny may be one way we select for less intelligence, neoteny is not limited to physical characteristics, that does not mean we are not selecting for less intelligence. And again we are seeing it in ALL species not just the ones we selected for neoteny. the change here is too large and widespread to be simple lack of pressure or spandrel, these organisms have only had a few hundred or thousand generations. And none for which it is not true. there is even a direct correlation between tameness and brain shrinkage in some species. https://www.science.org/content/article/tamer-cow-smaller-brain

Comment: Interestingly species bred for aggression don't show this same loss, these are also the animals that are useless for labor. We also see that dogs are demonstratable less intelligent (problem solving) than wolves, https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsbl.2015.0489 because

Answer (score 7):

In this case, I am considering "the bronze age" to be the period from ~3200 BCE to ~1200 BCE. Note: The question is *not* which tasks they could perform, but which ones they *couldn't*. Here is a brief, but non-exhaustive list. I'll include some non-purely physical tasks, just for the sake of closer completionism.

- Potter (yes, a pottery wheel is *much* too fine of a craft for animals to master)
- Farmer (even mechanization hasn't replaced farmers, and it's considerably more advanced than domesticated animal labor)
- Smith (Silver, gold, bronze, copper, etc)
- Prostitute (*hopefully* not replaced by magpies or elephants, but up to you)
- Baker
- Brewer
- Priest
- Scribe
- Engineer
- Mason
- Quarryman
- Miner
- Weaver
- Tailor
- Doctor
- Tanner
- Cobbler
- Carpenter
- Driver
- Sailor
- Carter
- Merchant
- Money changer
- Musician
- Soldier
- Cartwright
- Cooper
- Lumberjack
- Barber
- Butcher
- Shipwright
- Fletcher
- Leatherworker
- Charcoal Burner
- Oarsman

Comment: hi @DanielB, you claim "completeness" but I wonder where did you get that list from ? It is not a complete list, there's millers, shoemakers, roofers, locksmiths and cooks as well, and many professions that have now disappeared, like woolpainters, watchmen and wheelwrights.. Next, the opener did not ask for a list of all professions. How would your answer relate to the question ? this is about *animals* doing tasks. There is no way a baker, or a locksmith or a barber could be replaced by a mammoth or a bird. You need hands for these tasks.

Comment: @Goodies 1) I literally said 'non-exhaustive', 2) the question, and my answer, is not which tasks they *could* perform, but which ones they *couldn't*, 3) a shoemaker is a cobbler.

Comment: Ahh @DanielB you keep ignoring the *animals* there are: 1) mammoths and 2) magpies, your list should be pruned accordingly, a lot of these professions are *not* suitable, there are *no hands* !

Comment: @Goodies The question was edited to ask for jobs that could not be performed by animals. I guess this is where the confusion and misunderstanding came from. It was reverted to the original now.

Comment: @Otkin you're right actually.. more answers ignored that fact.. but the above list gives nearly all professions "for completionism". But it ignores what the animals could, or could not do.  It states soldier, driver, and miner, which are professions that could be executed by mammoths. A magpie could serve as a weaver, a scribe, or a musician.

Comment: @Goodies My comment was only aimed to resolve the misunderstanding. I have no comments regarding the content of this answer. I am not familiar with the topic enough to have an opinion.

Comment: @Goodies Again, I literally said my list is *non-exhaustive*. And I think you'll find that our modern day has soldiers, drivers, and miners, despite mechanized labor and computerization that far outstrips the capabilities of beasts. The tank, the GPS, and the jackhammer did not make human labor obsolete. The mammoth and the magpie certainly won't.

Comment: Mammoth barber with a straight edge?  No thanks ...

Answer (score 3):

**Mammoths:**

*Transportation:*
Hauling and transporting would be the obvious answers to this one. I'm assuming you've already considered that. If someone could keep them fed (no easy feat, there is debate on how much they would eat a day but people agree that it be a **lot**.). That food requirement might make smaller breeds of these creatures more practical for common use. For farms or transport of persons or goods, smaller breeds would be best and save the massive ones for large-scale hauling.

*Warfare:*
Mammoths could dominate on a Bronze Age battlefield. A mammoth that could be trained to plow straight into humans could turn the tide of a battle. Using them as pack animals for hauling an army's wagons would also be viable. Same for hauling/pushing siege weapons.

*Food:*
A mammoth packs a good amount of meat. As well as hide, fur, and ivory. Even milk if you're into that.

*Miscellaneous:*
It's believed that mammoths cleared away snow with their tusks to get at grass during the winter so a city would utilize a mammoth team to clear their streets when it snows. Training them to perform tricks for an audience also wouldn't be out of the question. There was a dog breed whose entire job was to run in a wheel to turn a meat spit over a fire, don't see why a mammoth trunk couldn't do the same. Same with other repetitive motions like fanning a forge.

**Magpies:**

*Messenger:*
Depending on the level of intelligence you want to allow they could be used to deliver messages. Repeating the message word for word. This could be even more useful if the birds could be trained to recognize individual people or uniforms.

*Search and retrieve:*
Magpies like shiny things, so do humans. They like food more. Training a magpie to search for food or other animals to hunt and bring them to the attention of their human handlers would be useful.

*Record keeping?*
The question mark on this one because it is up to your definition of "very good memory, can learn huge numbers of words". If I could train my bird to recount certain bits of information in response to different commands I certainly would. Especially if I didn't trust that information to be written down.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on some physical tasks the animals could perform? I was thinking they might be able to work a pottery wheel, but I don't know how much finesse those require, and ditto for other forms of simple manufacturing..

Answer (score 2):

My two cents..

Your **magpies** could keep to their old profession: silver was a very precious metal. Magpies love to steal shiny objects, so you could train them to steal silver for you. Let them gather all the treasures hide in a secret place.. also, if you have 100,000 years, magpies will develop language along with humans. By conversation, they can help humans to structure their language. Magpies could become the first *messengers*.

The **mammoths**.. small ones will be employed to take care of the children and play with them. Small mammoths serve as intelligent pets, keeping an eye on the surroundings, and providing emotional support, like Earth dogs can do. They may be able to prepare a meal.

You could learn the big mammoths to help building settlements and fences around settlements, or to prepare land for agriculture. Digging, for water, or to find copper. Unlike the animals helping Earth bronze age people developing agriculture, these animals would be able to perform tasks autonomously, really freeing men of work.

Answer (score 1):

All labor that required the use of small hand motions and opposable thumbs would still require human labor, as would everything involving literacy or supervising others labor.

The tasks animals can be used for, even extremely intelligent animals would be limited based off of their body plan and senses. For example, your mammoths would be excellent at hauling lumber, as Asian Elephants are used in that very task in modern Thailand, but you really couldn’t employ an elephant to bake a cake.